# How do I align the header text in TableColumns?

Tags: header, alignment, javafx-8, tablecolumn

How do I align the text in the header of my JavaFX TableColumns (both TableView and TreeTableView)?

(The javadoc for TableColumn doesn't have one word on alignment and barely anything on the header.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this css:

```
.table-view .column-header .label{
    -fx-alignment:CENTER_LEFT
}
```